# Parallel execution and termination of multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a simple application in which I create 3 threads inside a class to ping 3 different websites and note the time taken to do so.

I wish to enhance it by seeing which thread out of the 3 executes successfully first and terminating the other two .

Which class of the JDK would be helpful in doing so ? and how ?

Sample code to ping websites :

```
public static boolean pingUrl(final String address) {

 try {

  final URL url = new URL("http://" + address);

  final HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 10); // mTimeout is in seconds

  final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

  urlConn.connect();

  final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

  if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

   System.out.println("Time (ms) : " + (endTime - startTime));
   System.out.println("Ping to "+address +" was success");

   return true;
  }
 } catch (final MalformedURLException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
 } catch (final IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: How are you pinging the websites?

Comment: @vandale added sample code

Comment: In Order to properly terminate the threads, you have to abort the `urlConn.connect()`, which I don't think is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wish to enhance it by seeing which thread out of the 3 executes successfully first and terminating the other two .

I would use an `ExecutorService` combined with a `ExecutorCompletionService`.  Then, when the first `Future` is returned from the completion service when the first task completes, you would call `shutdownNow()` on the  `ExecutorService`.

The [javadocs for `ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) are pretty good and show how to use it.

```
// maybe you want 10 threads working on your tasks
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); 
CompletionService<Result> ecs
     = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(threadPool);
for (Callable<Result> task : tasks) {
    // submit your tasks to the completion service, they run in the thread-pool
    ecs.submit(task);
}
// once you get one result
Future<Result> future = ecs.take();
// kill the rest of the tasks
threadPool.shutdownNow();
Result result = future.get();
// probably will need to close the thread connections, see below
// maybe call threadPool.awaitShutdown(...) here to wait for the others to die
```

The only problem with this mechanism is that this will only interrupt the threads.  In your case they are going to be stuck in `urlConn.connect();` which is not interruptible.  Once the `ecs.take()` returns, you are going to have to run back over your tasks and call `disconnect()` on the  the `HttpURLConnection` that are still in progress.  Even then I'm not sure if it will stop a connection that is currently underway.   If that doesn't work then you may need to switch to using Apache `HttpClient` or some other class that you can close to stop the threads from waiting longer.

```
for (Callable<Result> task : tasks) {
   // you'll need to do something like this
   task.closeConnection();
}
```

In your case, your task might look something like:

```
public class MyPingTask implements Callable<Boolean> {
    private String address;
    public MyPingTask(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
         // obviously the pingUrl code could go right here
         return pingUrl(address);
    }
}
```

Here is the [Java tutorial on `ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) and related classes.

Comment: Nice answer! Possible workaround for the interruption-issue: Instead of `newFixedThreadPool(...)` use a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` with overridden method `newTaskFor(Callable)`. It returns a custom `RunnableFuture` that is 'aware' of the fact that the `Callable` owns a `HttpURLConnection` (or `HttpClient` request object) and closes its connection/aborts its request in its `cancel` method.

Comment: Never done that @isnot2bad but it sounds like it would work.  Certainly not for the junior thread programmers of course.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) may be useful. The main idea that spawned thread writes some value to `BlockingQueue` when finished and gracefully closes on `InterruptedException`

For example:

```
public void runPing(List<String> urls) {
    Collection<Thread> runningThreads = new ArrayList<>(urls.size());
    final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(urls.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        final String url = urls.get(i);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pingUrl(url);
                queue.add(1);
            }
        });
        runningThreads.add(t);
    }
    try {
        queue.poll(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        interruptChilds(runningThreads);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        interruptChilds(runningThreads);
    }
}

private void interruptChilds(Collection<Thread> runningThreads) {
    for (Thread t : runningThreads) {
        t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Please note that in there are no handling of `InterruptedException`. It should be added in your method